# php regex to check for more than 2 letters

Tags: php

I would like to check a string with regex. I want to have an if statement to do as follows:

If string contains more than 2 alphabet characters then do something. It is case sensative and should not contain any other characters except for upper case letters.

Here is what I have but doesn't work properly. Only alphabetical letters allowed

`if(preg_match("/[A-Z]{2}/", $value) != 2) {
    // do something
}`

Comment: did you want it to be case sensitive?

Comment: Are the characters limited to A-Z? If so, do the letters need to be consecutive or can other characters be between them? Some examples of the inputs you need to process would be helpful.

Comment: yes, its case sensitive as well. Must be upper case letters only. Cannot contain non alphabet characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can match for the valid case (2 alphabetical characters) and then negate the result:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z]{2}$/", $value)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough for two **characters** (including numbers):

```
if (!preg_match('/^\w{2}$/', $value)) {
    // Do something
}
```

This only matches letters:

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z]{2}$/i', $value)) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: `\w` matches numbers.

Comment: sorry i updated my post to mention Uppercase letters only. Cannot contain any other characters except letters.

Comment: @chris You're right - I was just editing my answer when you posted your comment :).

Comment: As I read it neither of these meet the question `more than 2 alphabet characters then do something`. Also your second regex has an extra "/". You're only checking for 2 characters and need to close the `if`s in both conditions, you're only closing preg_match.

Comment: thanks for trying but it didnt work. The answer from @Gergo does work `'/^[A-Z]{2}$/'`